# Accessing header params in javax.websocket

Tags: java, websocket

I have the following simple websocket example:

```
package com.bfaconsultora.rest.europa.resources;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;


@ServerEndpoint("/api/europa/qr/websocket")
public class QrWebSocket {
    private Set<Session> sessions = new HashSet<>();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen (
        Session session
    ) {        
        sessions.add(session);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void handleMessage(String message, Session session) {
        try {
            for (int c = 0; c < 100; c++) {
                for (Session s : sessions) {
                    s.getBasicRemote().sendText("{\"value\" : \"" + (c + 1) + "\"}");
                }
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        sessions.remove(session);
    }
}
```

running on **Apache Tomcat 9**.
Is it possible to access header params (I need it for authentication purposes)? Could you please point me the right direction?

Thank you in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible (or at last not a common practice) to read header params from a web socket. The usual way to authenticate is to send auth information in the first message, but there are other ways.

I found this [reading](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/authentication.html) very useful.

Regards to everyone.